# Existe algum meio de passar um varivel Python para um script em javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

> Tenho um código em JavaScript que é acionado a partir de um outro
> código python, em python eu criei uma variável que puxa um objeto json
> do banco de dados, e preciso consultar essa variável para saber quais
> relatório vou atualizar com o código Javascript

```
const objeto = {
    "ticket1": ["Relatorio BI 1"],
    "ticket2": ["Relatorio BI 2"]
}

console.log('Clicker Injected');
const rows=document.querySelectorAll('#artifactContentList .row');
console.log(rows);
rows.forEach(row=>{
    objeto.chave1.forEach(valor =>{
        if(row.childNodes[4].innerText === valor){
            const button = row.children[1].firstChild.children[1]
            button.click()
    }
    })
});
```

> Existe algum meio de pegar essa variável em python e coloca-la em
> JavaScript, ou, existe alguma forma de vincular o JavaScript ao banco
> de dados Postgresql
>
> A baixo a chamada no código python do script em java.

**PS: A variável que vem do banco de dados está armazenada usando a biblioteca Pandas**

```
for n,w in workspaces.items():
        try:
            nav.driver.execute_script(clickerScript)
        except Exception as e:
            errH.report('Ocorreu erro na atualização do workspace:{n}'.format(n=n),e)
            nav.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Ele é um código Python(selenium) que executa em script que vai até o http do Power BI e atualiza os relatórios em uma determinada hora.

Comment: Inclui uma imagem da chamada do código javaScript em Python.

Comment: Quero adicionar em um objeto json os nomes dos relatórios que tem que ser atualizados, e assim fazer a atualização.

Comment: Não use imagens para código prefira texto pois facilita a cópia para testes e leitores de pagina para programadores com deficiência visual não conseguem interpretar a imagem.

Comment: Modificado.....

Comment: De que forma posso fazer isto?

Comment: Ok, mas como faço para pegar esse valor do outro lado, dentro do javascript?

Comment: Por exemplo em python defina `variavel_python = 10` , ainda um python `script_string= f"let varpy = ${variavel_python};"` quando injetar o código contido em `script_string` no contexto javascript existirá uma variável `varpy` cujo o valor é 10;

Comment: Muito obrigado Augusto, excelente ajuda!

Comment: PS: para criar fstring de múltiplas linhas use três aspas `'''` para abrir e para fechar. assim: `teste = f''' texto de multiplas linhas '''`